# How to properly lift errors from Joi.alternatives?

Tags: typescript, joi

I have a field that can be one of many types. Each type has a different schema. I tried to use [`Joi.alternatives`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0#alternatives) to validate the request JSON. However, I want to lift the errors from the inner validation functions. Currently `alternatives` override it with it's error message.

For example, I have a field call `customer` that can either be a `business` or a `person`. If the customer is a `person`, then only `name` field is present.

```json
{
  "customer": {
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
  ...
}
```

On the other hand, if the customer is a `business` then both `name` and `businessCode` fields are present.

```json
{
  "customer": {
    "name": "My Company",
    "businessCode": 1820
  },
  ...
}
```

I do validation like:

```js
Joi.alternatives()
   .match("one")
   .try(
     Joi.object<Person>({
       name: Joi.string().required()
     }).unknown(false).required(),
     Joi.object<Business>({
       name: Joi.string().required(),
       businessCode: Joi.number().integer().positive().required()
     }).unknown(false).required()
   )
```

I use `match('one')` to specify that either `business` or `person` should be matched, but not both. When I pass an invalid `businessCode` like `{"businessCode": -999}`, Joi throws

> "customer" does not match any of the allowed types

which is not as helpful as providing a message like "the business code is negative, which is not allowed as a business". We know that this is a business because a person does not have any business codes. How can I lift the error from the inner validations? One other alternative I thought of is to do validation twice, validate the fields after we validate the field existence, but I'm not sure how to do this within Joi.

Comment: Why do you need to use `Joi.alternatives()`? You can just define the object with `name.required()` and `businessCode.optional()`... you can then send just `name` or both `name` and `businessCode`... If you just send `{ businessCode: -999 }` is going to throw an error saying that `name` is required, and `businessCode` must be a positive number.

Comment: @soltex Yes you are correct, but I think `Joi.alternatives()` seems a bit more modular and manageable. Imagine that each of the `business` / `person` is a very big object, and there might be more than just `business` / `person`. Also typing seems to work nicely with each of the entities separated as well (otherwise, we would need a union type).

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, `Joi.alternatives()` doesn't give good error messages. Not sure if this will apply to your scenario, but you can try play around with [.with](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectwithkey-peers-options). If you set up `.with('businessCode', 'name')`, whenever you send `businessCode`, `name` will be required, and you can avoid using `Joi.alternatives()`. If it doesn't work you might have to parse the error manually.

Comment: I checked out `with()`. Seems like it'll be a fit for some cases, but not in what I am describing. That would likely require a god object with all of the fields and `with` conditions setup, which would be very unmaintainable. Can you add a example of how to parse the error manually, specifically for `Joi.alternatives()`, as an answer?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to manually parse the errors. I thought it will be possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in joi latest.

In your scenario you say

> "the business code is negative, which is not allowed as a business"

but in order to establish this you are implying the matched alternative here is "Business" when in reality (and from joi's PoV) the input has failed the Business schema as much as it failed the Person schema.

For the problem of reporting specific errors when working with `alternatives`, my solution is to manually run the input thru the different schemas and then create an aggregated response that looks something like "this input failed schema A because this is missing X and failed schema B because it is missing Y"